# SMTP error-not able to send zip file

Tags: java, spring, email, smtp

I am trying to send a zip file having .csv in it over SMTP server through my application and getting the below error:

> org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection
>   failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not
>   connect to SMTP host: 10.56.131.8, port: 25; nested exception is:
>     java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect. Failed
>   messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP
>   host: 10.56.131.8, port: 25;   nested exception is:
>     java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect; message
>   exceptions (1) are: Failed message 1: javax.mail.MessagingException:
>   Could not connect to SMTP host: 10.56.131.8, port: 25;   nested
>   exception is:     java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out:
>   connect

Error occurs only in case of zip & not normal .csv file.

Any suggesstions.

Comment: show us the code and what is size of zip file?

Comment: size of zip is 2 kb